# Calculate Invoice - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, billing

I have a dataset like this:

| Date | Contract | value | Monthly total | Invoice Date | Amount to be paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | Contract 1 | 180 | 380 | 01/01/2023 |  |
| 01/01/2023 | Contract 1 | 200 | 380 | 01/01/2023 |  |
| 01/02/2023 | Contract 1 | 800 | 1000 |  |  |
| 01/02/2023 | Contract 1 | 200 | 1000 |  |  |
| 01/03/2023 | Contract 1 | 150 | 550 | 01/03/2023 | 1380 |
| 01/03/2023 | Contract 1 | 400 | 550 | 01/03/2023 | 1380 |
| 01/04/2023 | Contract 1 | 350 | 950 |  |  |
| 01/04/2023 | Contract 1 | 600 | 950 |  |  |
| 01/05/2023 | Contract 1 | 220 | 330 | 01/05/2023 | 1500 |
| 01/05/2023 | Contract 1 | 110 | 330 | 01/05/2023 | 1500 |
| 01/01/2023 | Contract 2 | 50 | 150 | 01/01/2023 |  |
| 01/01/2023 | Contract 2 | 100 | 150 | 01/01/2023 |  |
| 01/02/2023 | Contract 2 | 200 | 350 | 01/02/2023 | 150 |
| 01/02/2023 | Contract 2 | 150 | 350 | 01/02/2023 | 150 |
| 01/03/2023 | Contract 2 | 100 | 300 | 01/03/2023 | 350 |
| 01/03/2023 | Contract 2 | 200 | 300 | 01/03/2023 | 350 |

The value column the monthly value, while the "Monthly total" column tells me the monthly total (given by the sum of the values over the same month). For example, Contract 1, date 01/01/2023, 380 "monthly total"(180+380).
The "Invoice Date" column tells me the date on which the billing is to take place.

I should find a way to calculate the amount to be paid for each billing date (Column "Amount to be paid"). For example: Contract 1; Invoice Date 01/03/2023; Amount to be paid: 1380 (1000 of 01/02/2023 + 380 of 01/01/2023).

So, with respect to the invoice date, i have to consider the months before until the previous billing.

I tried something like this thanks to another post, but it doesn't work:

```
Amount to be paid = 
  var thisBillDate = table[Invoice Date]
  var prevBillDate = CALCULATE(
    MAX(table[invoice Date]),
    ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Contract]),
   table[Invoice Date] < thisBillDate
  )
  var result = CALCULATE(
    SUM(table[Monthly total]),
    ALLEXCEPT(tale, table[Contract], table[Date]),
    prevBillDate < table[Invoice Date] &&  table[Invoice Date] <= thisBillDate)

  return IF(NOT ISBLANK(table[Invoice Date]), COALESCE(result, 0))
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Where is the other post? Why not continue there if not correct? Did you delete it? Charming.

Comment: I didn't hear back on the other post for over a day. So I thought I'd recreate it since the table structure also changed.
Could you still help me?

Comment: Perhaps, the above isn't one table though, is it? Why are there some invoice dates without amounts?

Comment: I brought the billing date from another table via a lookupvalue with the "contract" key.
Contract dates without amounts are empty because they are the "Stard date" of the contract, therefore they have no values in previous months.
So contract 1 for example, starts on 01/01/2023. The first invoicing takes place on 01/03/2023 and the amount is given by the monthly values between 01/01/2023 and 01/03/2023 (therefore January and February). The second on 01/05/2023 and the range is between 01/03/2023 (previous invoice) and 01/05 2023 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have two tables:
Table: `Bill`

| Date | Contract | value |
| --- | --- | --- |

Table: `Invoice`

| Contract | Invoice Date |
| --- | --- |

Add a Calculated Column to table `Invoice` with:

```
Amount to be paid = 
  var thisContract = [Contract]
  var thisInvoiceDate = [Invoice Date]
  var prevInvoiceDate = CALCULATE(
    MAX(Invoice[Invoice Date]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Invoice, Invoice[Contract]),
    Invoice[Invoice Date] < thisInvoiceDate
  )
  var result = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Bill[value]),
    Bill[Contract] = thisContract && 
    Bill[Date] >= prevInvoiceDate &&
    Bill[Date] < thisInvoiceDate
  )

  return result
```

[image]

Comment: Please Accept answer for the benefit of all.